# Share Titanium project on GitLab

Tags: eclipse, svn, appcelerator, gitlab, commit

I'm using Source Tree to manage GitLab content, it's possible to use the 'Team' option inside the Project Explorer in Appcelerator?

I've downloaded the eclipse SVN plugin (subversion) for Appcelerator, but after setting the repository location information I'm getting this message:

- an error occurred while accessing the repository entry